# Is it better to use aggregation over inheritance when creating a generic CRUD component?

Tags: java, inheritance, aggregation

I have a question. I have these classes:

```
public interface CRUDService<MODEL extends BaseModel<ID>,ID extends Serializable>
{
     List<MODEL> findAll();
     MODEL findById(ID id);
     // + delete, save & update methods
}

public abstract class AbstractCRUDService<MODEL extends BaseModel<ID>,ID extends Serializable> implements CRUDService<MODEL,ID>
{
     //overriding the CRUDService interface methods here.
}
```

Is it better to extend each service from `AbstractCRUDService` like this:

```
public class DefaultProductService extends AbstractCRUDService<ProductModel,Long> implements ProductService
{ //some methods here}
```

or should I remove `abstract` from `AbstractCRUDService` and inject this service in the `DefaultProductService` ?

```
public class DefaultProductService implements ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private CRUDService<ProductModel,Long> crudService;

    // override "ProductService" methods here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement.

If all `Model Types`, need the same CRUD implementation, you can go with your 2nd approach: composition.

However, if different Model objects require different CRUD implementations, the inheritance would fit better. For example, for all `ProductModel`s `Del(obj)` will remove the object from the DB table, however, for all `OrderModel`s `Del(obj)` doesn't remove the data, instead, it does something else, throw an exception, for example.

Comment: Oh, so when I need another implementation for `delete` method I simply override it in the main class in case of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You need to prefer composition over inheritance

here a really good post to read about it

[composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance/53354#53354)